# Saving an object in memory for debugging elsewhere

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, object, ios-simulator

I've got an object here that gets generated after my application initializes and gets all of its data.  The object is fairly complicated and holds a decent amount of properties.  Unfortunately, due to the nature of the project, I am unable to run it in the iPhone simulator.  So instead, I must run it each time on a physical iPhone so that this object can be initialized.

Is there any way for me to save this object after it has been initialized and make it act as a constant so that I can continue to work with it in a new project using the iPhone Simulator?

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear exactly what you're trying to accomplish. That said, you can probably implement the NSCoding protocol in your object, serialize it to a plist, then transfer the plist back to your Mac and use it to load up a copy of the (initialized) object the next time the app runs.

Take a look at the [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047-SW1) and the [NSCoding Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I'll take a look at that.

A more general example of what I'm trying to do is this:  It takes a while for this class object to initialize (60+seconds) and it must be done on the iphone.  What I'd like to do is take that initialized class and move it over to a sandbox environment where I can work with it faster and easier, to prove out some logic.

Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, and I think what I've outlined should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can save you object into device OS using for example some serializing and writeToFile: method (or NSFileManager). Then you should extract this saved file from device using Xcode -> Organizer. Find there devices folder then installed applications. There is access to internal Application folders, e.g. Documents, Library and Tmp. Make export of files you saved before and use in Simulator.